# What should the captive say?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

You are lost in a jungle and suddenly get caught by a tribal group who are cannibals. They keep you captive and however think of offering you a second chance to save your life.

**Their leader says- "We will give you one chance to say something. It should be a sentence, not a question. It should not be a single word. This will make it easy for us to decide which way to kill you. If that sentence is a truth, you will be burnt to death. If it is a lie, we will shoot you."**

What should the captive say to escape this tragic death?

(Assume this tribe knows how to figure out what is true and what is false even if it is something personal to the captive.)

Comment: I'll be surprised if some variation of this hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is for the captive to say one of the following: 
Either...

> I will die by getting shot.

or...

> I will not die by getting burnt to death.

The reasoning is simple:

> Both of these are the same. If the leader thinks it's the truth, he will get burnt, but by that logic he should be lying, and therefore shot, but it's the truth, so it's a paradox! Same logic for if it is a lie; if it is a lie, he gets shot, but he said the truth, so he's supposed to be burnt, but he lied about that, so again, a paradox!

Answer (score 1):

You should tell

> You are going to shot me.

this is a famous paradox, I think. In this way

> They can't shot you otherwise your statement would be true (and they will have to burn you). But they can't burn you either otherwise your statement would be false (and they will have to shot you).

Anyway

> They cannot set you free either

So I'm not sure this is a good answer.